# Invalid amount of variables values while passing json as request url using resttemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

i am consuming a rest webservice using spring resttemplate class blow is my url which is given by 3rd party application vendor

```
[http://10.123.84.143:8080/ServiceWebService/updateModelMPData.do?lmgCode=186353&applicationId=8&uuid=9a26038f-6dd1-40b6-b847-f2fd16366fc0&jsonData={No. of Organizations -: 1,No. of officals  -: 20,No. of Ers  -: 5}
```

so according to his requirement i need pass the json values dynamically like i mentioned above 1,20,5 are i am getting from database and i am passing. while i am executing using resttemplate exchange method and along with all the parameters i am passing i am getting the below exception

EXCEPTION ------------------- Invalid amount of variables values in

```
[http://10.123.84.143:8080/ServiceWebService/updateModelMPData.do?lmgCode=186353&applicationId=8&uuid=9a26038f-6dd1-40b6-b847-f2fd16366fc0&jsonData={No. of Organizations -: 1,No. of officals  -: 20,No. of Ers  -: 5}: expected 1; got 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid amount of variables values in [http://10.123.84.143:8080/ServiceWebService/updateModelMPData.do?lmgCode=186353&applicationId=8&uuid=9a26038f-6dd1-40b6-b847-f2fd16366fc0&jsonData={No. of Organizations -: 1,No. of officals  -: 20,No. of Ers  -: 5}: expected 1; got 0
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriTemplate.expand(UriTemplate.java:127)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:400)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:377)
    at com.org.ep.trg.webservice.ModelGPStatusController.GpStatusSubmit(ModelGPStatusController.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:585)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at in.nic.pes.common.interceptor.AUthenticatUserFilter.doFilter(AUthenticatUserFilter.java:23)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.org.ep.help.HelpFilter.doFilter(HelpFilter.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.org.ep.interceptor.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:37)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

here my doubt is how to pass json values dynamically in url and which method is the best option to consume a rest service using resttemplate.
here one more thing is i didn't  see the rest service method implementation method, i only know the url which is i mentioned above 
thanks for looking my query.

this is my code which is causing the the exception in my controller class

```
  ResponseEntity<ModelStatusEntity> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, null, ModelStatusEntity.class);
```

Comment: **Don't pass json values in a URL.**

Comment: Now show us the code that generates this exception.

Comment: then how can i pass the json values

Comment: And also the server side code!!1

Comment: In the body of the request.

Comment: ResponseEntity<ModelStatusEntity> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, null, ModelStatusEntity.class);

Comment: above is the method i am using in my controller class

Comment: No. Edit your question. Add the code there.

Comment: as i mentioned above i don't know the server code only i got the url and i have to call while ;passing json values in url

Comment: so tell me how to pass in the body of the request

Answer (score 1):

`RestTemplate`, before making the request, expands the given URI (potentially containing URI template variables) with any given uri variables.

The syntax for template variables is described in part in the [`URITemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriTemplate.html) javadoc.

> A URI template is a URI-like String that contains variables enclosed
>   by braces ({}), which can be expanded to produce an actual URI.

In your URI, you have this small piece

```
jsonData={No. of Organizations -: 1,No. of officals  -: 20,No. of Ers  -: 5}
```

Notice the `{..}` brackets. Everything within them is interpreted as URI template variable. But you haven't provided any URI variable to resolve it with. Notice again how it states

> expected 1; got 0

My suggested solution is to add the JSON (real JSON, not what you tried to use there) to the body. Other solutions are to encode (escape) the `{}` so that they aren't interpreted as URI template variables.

Comment: what  you mean by real json, what i am trying to say is i have to get these 3 values from data base like 1,20,5 and i have to append with the given url, so now tell me how to pass real json

Comment: [http://10.123.84.143:8080/ServiceWebService/updateModelMPData.do?lmgCode=186353&applicationId=8&uuid=9a26038f-6dd1-40b6-b847-f2fd16366fc0&jsonData        upto jsonData url is static and in jsonData i have to pass these 3 values so how can i..?

Comment: @Sthogari I don't know how you generated the text `{No. of Organizations -: 1,No. of officals  -: 20,No. of Ers  -: 5}`, but it is not JSON. Look at the other `exchange` methods that show how to pass an `HttpEntity` as the request body.

Comment: i did not generated this text just i am trying to call with exact url which is given by client but values are dynamic values

Comment: any how thanks for your time and suggestions i will try to pass in entity and i will get back to u.

Answer (score 0):

This string is **not** JSON:

```
{No. of Organizations -: 1,No. of officals  -: 20,No. of Ers  -: 5}
```

JSON would be:

```
{NoOfOrganizations: 1, NoOfOfficals: 20, NoOfErs 5}
```

You can't use JSON to parse a non-JSON string. You must parse this yourself, or change other side to generate actual JSON.

---

Also, the query parameter is unencoded. Encoded it would be:

```
%7BNo.%20of%20Organizations%20-%3A%201%2CNo.%20of%20officals%20%20-%3A%2020%2CNo.%20of%20Ers%20%20-%3A%205%7D
```

And as others have commented, you should not send JSON text as a query parameter. The URL has a limited length, as low as 2000, so when having values that could be long, the values should be sent in the body of a POST, not as query parameters of a GET.

Comment: {"NoOfOrganizations": 1, "NoOfOfficals": 20, "NoOfErs": 5} i passed like this but it didn't work.

Comment: that's what i want to know please tell me how to pass in the body

Comment: i also tried with encoded url and i tried some other methods from rest template non of them or working so give some code how to call

Comment: To help, you need to show how you're building the `uri` parameter.

Comment: [http://10.123.84.143:8080/ServiceWebService/updateModelMPData.do?lmgCode=186353&applicationId=8&uuid=9a26038f-6dd1-40b6-b847-f2fd16366fc0&jsonData upto jsonData it is static and in jsonData i am getting the values from db and passing